# forEach Array in Array print all results in one line

Tags: javascript, arrays

please need your help as I am still learning. I've been looking for 2 days and I've come as far as here. Now I've tried various things and just can't get any further.

```
 var txt ='%xt%ain%1%0%{"A":{"DOA":1,"SP":1,"BL":[],"BC":[],"M":[{"OID":6233759,"DUM":false,"N":"Kilian29","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":39783,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":70,"CF":23,"HF":23,"PRE":1,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":786,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7492461,919,53,1],[0,7577432,920,49,4]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6238489,"DUM":false,"N":"JohnDoe","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":13509737,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":65,"CF":18,"HF":18,"PRE":0,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":1086,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7452613,926,66,4],[0,7494756,925,63,1]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6233816,"DUM":false,"N":"Skelletor98","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":5319690,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":70,"CF":0,"HF":0,"PRE":0,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":707,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7492496,916,52,1],[0,7577439,918,57,4]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6233751,"DUM":false,"N":"Gudrun1947","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":1644825,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":70,"CF":668,"HF":668,"PRE":2,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":888,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7492452,914,65,1],[0,7570865,916,63,4],[0,7590122,910,68,4]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6240471,"DUM":false,"N":"Lausebub","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":5319690,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":535,"CF":176,"HF":176,"PRE":2,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":956,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7478154,910,62,4],[0,7496479,909,61,1]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6240533,"DUM":false,"N":"Omikroon","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":5319690,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":505,"CF":460,"HF":460,"PRE":2,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":884,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7496534,911,57,1],[0,7578396,908,62,4]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6233743,"DUM":false,"N":"Constanze66","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":16341788,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":70,"CF":0,"HF":0,"PRE":0,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":742,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7450275,927,67,4],[0,7492447,923,69,1]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6233837,"DUM":false,"N":"KillerHai1","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":39783,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":70,"CF":0,"HF":0,"PRE":0,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":729,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7352073,918,61,4],[0,7492513,920,61,1]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6238188,"DUM":false,"N":"Kong25","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":39783,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":55,"CF":28,"HF":28,"PRE":1,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":784,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7494539,914,57,1],[0,7577664,914,63,4]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6238504,"DUM":false,"N":"Kaboom6","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":1644825,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":100,"AVP":515,"CF":67,"HF":67,"PRE":1,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":795,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7494766,934,65,1],[0,7578388,933,63,4],[0,7590074,936,67,4]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6233735,"DUM":false,"N":"Baltilde1","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":39783,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":65,"CF":171,"HF":171,"PRE":2,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":890,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":0,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7249101,924,70,4],[0,7492437,924,72,1]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6238471,"DUM":false,"N":"Pfeiffer2","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":13550873,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":65,"CF":34,"HF":34,"PRE":1,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":1344,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7163457,907,53,4],[0,7494740,914,54,1]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6238182,"DUM":false,"N":"Furry95","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":39783,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":70,"CF":0,"HF":0,"PRE":0,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":711,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7430487,924,61,4],[0,7494530,925,60,1]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6240038,"DUM":false,"N":"CatWoomen","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":8993831,"BGC2":11993088,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":500,"CF":28,"HF":28,"PRE":1,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":1202,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7418039,923,53,4],[0,7496059,924,54,1]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6233891,"DUM":false,"N":"Flipper78","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":39783,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":70,"CF":0,"HF":0,"PRE":0,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":708,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7450927,920,59,4],[0,7492557,927,58,1]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1}],"AID":146249,"N":"Klasse 1b","CF":549,"MP":13212,"D":"Beschreibt hier Eure Allianz!","ALL":"de","HP":1,"IS":1,"IA":0,"KA":0,"ML":0}}%'

if (txt.includes('%xt%ain%1%0%')) {
  var Alli = JSON.parse(txt.replace(/.*?({.*}).*/, "$1"))

  Alli.A.M.forEach(spieler);

  function spieler(item) {
    console.log("Allianz:" + item.AN + " ;" + "Name:" + item.N + ";" + " MP:" + item.MP + " ;" + "OID:" + item.OID + " ;" + "Level:" + item.L + "; " + "LL:" + item.LL + " ;" + "Taube:" + item.RPT + " ;" + item.AP)
  }
}
```

So far everything is as I want it.
Get all the information I need.
After that I tried the following:

```
Alli.A.M.forEach(spieler);

function spieler(item) {
  var burgen = item.AP.forEach(burgen);

  function burgen(burg) {
    var welt = burg[0]
    var art = burg[4]
    var x = burg[2]
    var y = burg[3]
    var koor = x + ":" + y

    if (welt === 0 && art === 4) {
      var bn = "AP"
    }
    if (welt === 0 && art === 1) {
      var bn = "HB"
    }
    if (welt === 0 && art === 3) {
      var bn = "HS Grün"
    }
    if (welt === 0 && art === 22) {
      var bn = "HM"
    }
    if (welt === 0 && art === 23) {
      var bn = "KT"
    }
    if (welt === 0 && art === 26) {
      var bn = "Monument"
    }
    if (welt === 0 && art === 28) {
      var bn = "Labor"
    }
    if (welt === 2 && art === 12) {
      var bn = "Eis"
    }
    if (welt === 2 && art === 3) {
      var bn = "Eis HS"
    }
    if (welt === 1 && art === 12) {
      var bn = "Sand"
    }
    if (welt === 1 && art === 3) {
      var bn = "Sand HS"
    }
    if (welt === 3 && art === 12) {
      var bn = "Feuer"
    }
    if (welt === 3 && art === 3) {
      var bn = "Feuer HS"
    }
    if (welt === 4 && art === 12) {
      var bn = "Wasser"
    }
    if (welt === 4 && art === 24) {
      var bn = "RohstoffInsel"
    }

    console.log("Allianz:" + item.AN + " ;" + "Name:" + item.N + ";" + " MP:" + item.MP + " ;" + "OID:" + item.OID + " ;" + "Level:" + item.L + "; " + "LL:" + item.LL + " ;" + "Taube:" + item.RPT + " ;" + bn + ":" + koor)
  }
}
```

`item.AP2` is the Second Array
This also works almost as I want, except for one small problem

[image]

If you look at the picture1, you will see the name twice under each other with the correct data.

What I would like to have now is where I can't get any further

[image]

I would like to output the data all in one line, like in picture 2.
I hope to be able to explain my problem as well as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every call to `console.log()` is on a new line. If you want everything on one line, concatenate them all into a string and log that at the end.

Have the function return the string instead of logging it. Then you can use `map()` to get all of them in an array, and `join()` to concatenate them.

```js
var txt ='%xt%ain%1%0%{"A":{"DOA":1,"SP":1,"BL":[],"BC":[],"M":[{"OID":6233759,"DUM":false,"N":"Kilian29","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":39783,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":70,"CF":23,"HF":23,"PRE":1,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":786,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7492461,919,53,1],[0,7577432,920,49,4]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6238489,"DUM":false,"N":"JohnDoe","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":13509737,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":65,"CF":18,"HF":18,"PRE":0,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":1086,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7452613,926,66,4],[0,7494756,925,63,1]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6233816,"DUM":false,"N":"Skelletor98","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":5319690,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":70,"CF":0,"HF":0,"PRE":0,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":707,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7492496,916,52,1],[0,7577439,918,57,4]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6233751,"DUM":false,"N":"Gudrun1947","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":1644825,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":70,"CF":668,"HF":668,"PRE":2,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":888,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7492452,914,65,1],[0,7570865,916,63,4],[0,7590122,910,68,4]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6240471,"DUM":false,"N":"Lausebub","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":5319690,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":535,"CF":176,"HF":176,"PRE":2,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":956,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7478154,910,62,4],[0,7496479,909,61,1]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6240533,"DUM":false,"N":"Omikroon","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":5319690,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":505,"CF":460,"HF":460,"PRE":2,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":884,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7496534,911,57,1],[0,7578396,908,62,4]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6233743,"DUM":false,"N":"Constanze66","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":16341788,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":70,"CF":0,"HF":0,"PRE":0,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":742,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7450275,927,67,4],[0,7492447,923,69,1]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6233837,"DUM":false,"N":"KillerHai1","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":39783,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":70,"CF":0,"HF":0,"PRE":0,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":729,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7352073,918,61,4],[0,7492513,920,61,1]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6238188,"DUM":false,"N":"Kong25","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":39783,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":55,"CF":28,"HF":28,"PRE":1,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":784,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7494539,914,57,1],[0,7577664,914,63,4]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6238504,"DUM":false,"N":"Kaboom6","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":1644825,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":100,"AVP":515,"CF":67,"HF":67,"PRE":1,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":795,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7494766,934,65,1],[0,7578388,933,63,4],[0,7590074,936,67,4]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6233735,"DUM":false,"N":"Baltilde1","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":39783,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":65,"CF":171,"HF":171,"PRE":2,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":890,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":0,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7249101,924,70,4],[0,7492437,924,72,1]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6238471,"DUM":false,"N":"Pfeiffer2","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":13550873,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":65,"CF":34,"HF":34,"PRE":1,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":1344,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7163457,907,53,4],[0,7494740,914,54,1]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6238182,"DUM":false,"N":"Furry95","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":39783,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":70,"CF":0,"HF":0,"PRE":0,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":711,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7430487,924,61,4],[0,7494530,925,60,1]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6240038,"DUM":false,"N":"CatWoomen","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":8993831,"BGC2":11993088,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":500,"CF":28,"HF":28,"PRE":1,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":1202,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7418039,923,53,4],[0,7496059,924,54,1]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1},{"OID":6233891,"DUM":false,"N":"Flipper78","E":{"BGT":3,"BGC1":14408394,"BGC2":39783,"SPT":4,"S1":29,"SC1":14408394,"S2":13,"SC2":11993088,"IS":1},"L":22,"LL":0,"H":0,"AVP":70,"CF":0,"HF":0,"PRE":0,"SUF":-1,"TOPX":-1,"MP":708,"R":0,"AID":146249,"AR":7,"AN":"Klasse 1b","RPT":0,"AP":[[0,7450927,920,59,4],[0,7492557,927,58,1]],"VP":[],"SA":0,"VF":0,"PF":0,"RRD":0,"TI":-1}],"AID":146249,"N":"Klasse 1b","CF":549,"MP":13212,"D":"Beschreibt hier Eure Allianz!","ALL":"de","HP":1,"IS":1,"IA":0,"KA":0,"ML":0}}%'

if (txt.includes('%xt%ain%1%0%')) {
  var Alli = JSON.parse(txt.replace(/.*?({.*}).*/, "$1"))
  Alli.A.M.forEach(spieler);
}

function spieler(item) {
  var burgen = item.AP.map(burgen);
  
  console.log("Allianz:" + item.AN + " ;" + "Name:" + item.N + ";" + " MP:" + item.MP + " ;" + "OID:" + item.OID + " ;" + "Level:" + item.L + "; " + "LL:" + item.LL + " ;" + "Taube:" + item.RPT + " ;" + burgen.join(' ;'))

  function burgen(burg) {
    var welt = burg[0]
    var art = burg[4]
    var x = burg[2]
    var y = burg[3]
    var koor = x + ":" + y

    if (welt === 0 && art === 4) {
      var bn = "AP"
    }
    if (welt === 0 && art === 1) {
      var bn = "HB"
    }
    if (welt === 0 && art === 3) {
      var bn = "HS Grün"
    }
    if (welt === 0 && art === 22) {
      var bn = "HM"
    }
    if (welt === 0 && art === 23) {
      var bn = "KT"
    }
    if (welt === 0 && art === 26) {
      var bn = "Monument"
    }
    if (welt === 0 && art === 28) {
      var bn = "Labor"
    }
    if (welt === 2 && art === 12) {
      var bn = "Eis"
    }
    if (welt === 2 && art === 3) {
      var bn = "Eis HS"
    }
    if (welt === 1 && art === 12) {
      var bn = "Sand"
    }
    if (welt === 1 && art === 3) {
      var bn = "Sand HS"
    }
    if (welt === 3 && art === 12) {
      var bn = "Feuer"
    }
    if (welt === 3 && art === 3) {
      var bn = "Feuer HS"
    }
    if (welt === 4 && art === 12) {
      var bn = "Wasser"
    }
    if (welt === 4 && art === 24) {
      var bn = "RohstoffInsel"
    }
    
    return bn + ":" + koor;

    
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Learned something again. Can't thank you enough for helping me so quickly :-)

Comment: @Jeffrey Did this answer/solution work for you then? Don’t forget to mark as accepted if so!

Comment: The solution worked very well for me.
Where can I accept it now?

Comment: Click the green check mark next to the question.